# NSIS installer .onInit and un.onInit run twice because of UAC

Tags: installation, nsis, uninstallation

Hello I am refactoring an old install script and run into the issue that the UAC plugin creates. Because of the `!insertmacro Init "installer"` the `.onInit` runs twice. The same goes for `!insertmacro Init "uninstaller"` and the `un.onInit` function.

Because of this, the installer and the uninstaller run twice which is not the behavior I want. [I have read that the UAC creates an inner process with elevated permissions](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/mediawiki/index.php?title=UAC_plug-in&oldid=17419#How_the_UAC_plug-in_works_with_user_and_admin_privileges), which IS required as it touches the `C:/` drive for example, but the outer process also runs the installer.

Because the install script is quite long I only paste the `.onInit` function. The whole `.nsi` script can be found [here](https://github.com/lfdversluis/tribler/blob/issue-2110-nsis-runs-twice/Tribler/Main/Build/Win/tribler.nsi).

Commenting out the line with the `!insertmacro` makes sure the `.onInit` function runs once, but does not run the installer anymore. So how can I make the installer and the uninstaller only run once, with the right (admin) permissions?

I appreciate any suggestion or answer :)

```
Function .onInit
MessageBox MB_OK "In .onInit"
  SetShellVarContext all

  !insertmacro Init "installer"

  System::Call 'kernel32::CreateMutexA(i 0, i 0, t "Tribler") i .r1 ?e'

  Pop $R0
  StrCmp $R0 0 checkinst

  MessageBox MB_OK "The installer is already running."
  Abort

  checkinst:
  ReadRegStr $R0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT}" "UninstallString"
  StrCmp $R0 "" done
  IfFileExists $R0 showuninstdialog done

  showuninstdialog:
  MessageBox MB_OKCANCEL|MB_ICONEXCLAMATION "${PRODUCT} is already installed. $\n$\nClick `OK` to remove the previous version or `Cancel` to cancel this upgrade." /SD IDCANCEL IDOK uninst
  Abort

  uninst:
    ClearErrors
    ; Laurens (2016-03-29): Retrieve the uninstallString stored in the register. Do NOT use $INSTDIR as this points to the current $INSTDIR var of the INSTALLER, 
    ; which is the default location at this point.
    ReadRegStr $R0 HKLM "Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT}" "UninstallString"
 MessageBox MB_OK "$R0"
    ExecWait '"$R0"' ;Do not copy the uninstaller to a temp file
    ReadRegStr $R0 HKLM "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\${PRODUCT}" "UninstallString"
    StrCmp $R0 "" done
    Abort
  done:

FunctionEnd
```

Comment: The .onInit code you pasted here does not match the code you linked to! The code you linked to has a clear problem, cannot really tell if the code pasted here has a problem without testing myself but I'm not going to do that until you clarify which code I'm supposed to test. Having some information about the NSIS/UAC plug-in/Windows versions used would also be nice...

Comment: @Anders I am pushing and trying several things while I type this. Sorry if it differs by now. Consider the code in the link the current code I am running. Also, I am building it on a Windows 2008 64 bit server and testing the installation procedure on a windows 10 machine, also 64 bit.

Comment: @Anders I have undone some of my experimental changes and pushed them. I will refrain pushing to it for now as it indeed it is confusing when people are looking at it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code you linked to (at least when I looked at it) called both `!insertmacro UAC_RunElevated` and `!insertmacro Init "installer"` in .onInit so no wonder it ran multiple times. After calling `!insertmacro UAC_RunElevated` you must always check `$0` because you might have to call `Quit` depending on its value!

I assume that Init macro is something I wrote(?) so it should work correctly ;)

I would personally recommend that you sacrifice the run checkbox on the finish page and then you probably don't have to use the UAC plug-in at all...

Comment: Thanks for your answer Anders, I had inserted the UAC_RunElevated as a test to see if the first thing I do is get additional permissions, maybe I could add a check to see if there are any Parameters that I can check for as @idleberg mentioned. Unfortunately, having only the !insertmacro Init "installer" there also makes it run twice.

Comment: I am going to check if I can do it without the UAC plugin as you suggested, thanks so far for your help and advice :)

Comment: I removed it, refactored the file here and there and it runs splendid. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

As far as I remember, the UAC plugin restarts the installer with a special parameter. You can check for that in your `.onInit` using [`GetParameters`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/AppendixE.html#getoptions) and [`GetOptions`](http://nsis.sourceforge.net/Docs/AppendixE.html#getoptions), then show a message conditionally:

```
# get all commandline parameters
${GetParameters} $0

# parse specific option
${GetOptions} $0 "/UAC:" $1

# do stuff
IfErrors 0 +2
MessageBox MB_OK "No admint" IDOK +2
MessageBox MB_OK "Admin"
```

Personally, I'd use `LogicLib` for the last part:

```
# do stuff
${If} $1 == ""
  MessageBox MB_OK "Not admin"
${Else}
 MessageBox MB_OK "Admin"
${Endif}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have added your suggested lines and it shows me an empty dialog on the fist run and `/UAC:<number> /NCRC` on the second run after the elevated permission dialog. So it sounds like I want the latter case, is there a way to check for this?